# How to Validate Rails 3 Relational Model?

Tags: validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

New to Rails and ActiveRecord, not sure how I can apply validation though multiple levels of relational model. I've searched all the tutorials that I can find are all validation in just one model.

How can I validate multiple relational models ?

Say I have multiple models, one model called **`field`** stores different type of attribute in sports game.(ex. final score, goals for, goals against etc) and another model **`value`** that stores all the actual values like game scores into the **`field`**

So I will have 2 classes

```
class Field < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :value       
end
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :field
end
```

How can I validate the value of each attributes in `value` model that are corresponding to it's `field` ?

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3 : You can create a file in your lib directory (**ensure** that that this file is loaded by your application) and put in a class with a validate method :

```
class HumanValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:base] << "This person is dead" unless check(human)
  end

  private

    def check(record)
      (record.age < 200) && (record.age > 0)
    end

end
```

In all model you want to validate, you invoke the validation with the of the class like this:

```
# app/models/person.rb
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with HumanValidator
end
```

Go read this, for validate novelty in rails 3, soure [link text](http://lindsaar.net/2010/1/31/validates_rails_3_awesome_is_true)

Comment: To automatically load all file in lib directory add config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib) to your config/application.rb file.